# Implement interface with suspend function from kotlin in java class

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have kotlin Interface with name `MediaBucketProvider`. this interface
have 1 suspend functuion that return entity list

```
interface MediaBucketProvider {

    suspend fun getMediaBuckets(bucketType: BucketType): List<MediaBucket>

}
```

When implementing this interface into kotlin class it worked fine. but when i want to
implement this interface in java class like this

```
class BucketProviderImpl implements MediaBucketProvider {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public Object getMediaBuckets(@NotNull BucketType bucketType, @NotNull Continuation<? super List<? extends MediaBucket>> $completion) {
      //return buckets
    }
}
```

build failed with below error

```
BucketProviderImpl.java:14: error: BucketProviderImpl is not abstract and does not override abstract method getMediaBuckets(BucketType,Continuation<? super List<MediaBucket>>) in MediaBucketProvider
class CustomLoaderJavaClass implements MediaBucketProvider {
^
```

When i remove `suspend` modifier from interface function build not failed anymore.

I see the `kotlin-to-java` implementation of Kotlin class that implement `MediaBucketProvider` interface its not different between `BucketProviderImpl` and java code of `KotlinBucketProviderImpl`

Comment: Probably `List<? extends MediaBucket>` should be `List<MediaBucket>` as stated in the exception/error.

Comment: thanks. the problem is `Continuation<? super List<? extends MediaBucket>> $completion` when i changed into `Continuation $completion` everything worked fine. i think this is bug of intellij idea code generator because i use Implement Member dialog for generate method overrides

Comment: Did coroutines ever worked in Java? I mean, I  don't think this is actually possible

Comment: Anything in kotlin finally compiles to JVM bytes code so we have coroutine in java but not with coroutine API in kotlin. we should use APIs like `Continuation` and etc for using coroutine APIs in the java. @Fred

Comment: @MehdiYari TIL! I really thought there were limitations there. I tried your example and replacing `Continuation<? super List<? extends MediaBucket>>` with `Continuation<? super List<MediaBucket>>` makes the code compile but the IDE complains. Adding `@JvmSuppressWildcards` to the declaration of the method helps with this - `suspend fun getMediaBuckets(bucketType: BucketType): List<@JvmSuppressWildcards MediaBucket>`. I have no idea why it doesn't work like you have it. To me `List<? extends MediaBucket>`  in java is a covariant of `List<MediaBucket` in kotlin which java should allow...